# Where do I go after collapsing the Dark World?

Tags: manifold-garden

In Manifold Garden I collapsed the Dark World and completed the Blue Level. I then walked through a door into a new area with long thin platforms covered in darkness. I wandered around but can't find anywhere to progress.

Where am I supposed to go after collapsing the Dark World and completing the Blue Level?

[image: Long thin platforms covered in darkness]